# Can I apply for a masters' if I already have one? (USA/Canada)

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-states, canada

I am planning to apply for another Masters' degree in CS in USA or Canada. But, the thing is I already have one masters' degree. Well, the reason I want to apply for another Masters' degree is because the one I have now is pretty...useless. I didn't learn any advanced courses like AI, Machine Learning, Distributed Systems, HCI, etc etc. Anyway, the list of reasons is very long so I will just skip it.

I worked for two years after my graduation and now I feel I want to go back to school to actually LEARN these CS courses.

I heard that if you already have a Masters' degree, you cannot apply to universities in USA or Canada? So, I wanted to know if this was true?

If yes, how can I find which universities will allow me to apply? I could go to each school website and look, but if someone already has a list, that would be very helpful.

Comment: So, to be clear, you have a master in CS and you want to get another master in CS?

Comment: @earthling yes. There are actually many people in my situation.

Comment: Go back for a certificate.. It's not that if you have a masters you can't apply for another, there are plenty of people with more than one masters. It's that if you have a masters in a particular subject, you cannot generally get one in the same degree. That is what the certificate programs and PhD programs are for.

Comment: You might also consider online courses if you just want to learn some more advanced theory. Take a look at Coursera or Udacity, they offer quite a bit.